# Refactoring to avoid redundancy with Pandas

Tags: xml, python-3.x, pandas, api, beautifulsoup

I've recently started to use the Pandas module(and Python) to manipulate and convert data into Excel. In doing so I have run into some redundancy in my code and wanted some advice on speeding up the process. At the moment I am using pd.series to add columns but I am needing to append it to a list before. I've only done this because I am unaware of how I can add these values directly to pd.series which I think would speed up the process. I am hoping for my code to be critiqued in order to learn how to set up my code to process the data more efficiently.

```
import requests
import csv
import json
import datetime as datetime
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

names = []
dates= []
IDs= []
countries = []

url = "url"
payload = {"PAYLOAD"}
response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print(response.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')

for data in soup.select('info'):
      ID = info.find('IDs').string
      date = info.find('dates').string
      name = info.find('names').string
      country = info.find('countries').string

      IDs.append(ID)
      dates.append(date)
      names.append(name)
      countries.append(country)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.Series(dates),
                     'ID': pd.Series(IDs),
                     'Name': pd.Series(names),
                     'Country': pd.Series(countries)
                   })

df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.sort_values(by=['Date'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
df = df[['Date', 'ID', 'Name', 'Country']]
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'pandaresult1.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct, it's outside of the loop I always have issues with formatting in Stack

Comment: That is correct, thank you!

Comment: You actually don't need to wrap your lists into series. Pandas will convert the data automatically to a column. And you also don't need to be afraid, the list would be stored as an object, so each row contains the same object (or a reference to the same object - the list). In case you try to assign a list to a column, that has not exactly as many elements as you have rows, you get an exception.

Comment: But wrapping it into a series would be needed, if you want to ensure a special type by using the `dtype` keyword.